# Loops with embedded Ruby and simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

[View Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2voo.png)

I am trying to loop through an array of values using simple_form.

Where @resume.employerorg holds the following values:

> ["Kaiser Santa Clara Hospital", "Kaiser Hospital",
> "UC Medical Center", "UCD Medical Center", "Some Hospital", "Sutter Auburn Faith Hospital", "Kaiser Roseville Hospital",
> "Sutter Roseville Hospital"]

In my view I have the following

```
<h3>7. Employer Names</h3>
  <%= simple_form_for @resume do |f| %>
      <% @resume.employerorg.each do |i| %>
        <%= f.input :employerorg,  label: 'First Employer' %> 
        <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

But this creates 8 input fields each filled with

> Kaiser Santa Clara Hospital Kaiser Hospital UC Medical Center UCD
> Medical Center Some Hospital Sutter Auburn Faith Hospital Kaiser
> Roseville Hospital Sutter Roseville Hospital

How would I fill each input with one individual item from the array rather than fill each input with the whole array 8 times?

Comment: The code above will produce 8 separate inputs and submit buttons. What do you want to achieve? You're essentially saying for each item in array, produce an input and a submit button.

Comment: *"Shouldn't the @resume.employerorg.each display only one employerorg in each input field?"*. No it shouldn't. `@resume` is the target object for the form and this part `<%= f.input :employerorg %>` will fill the input with what is essentially `target_object.public_send(:employerorg)` which is why it fills in every single array value in every single input.

Comment: Thanks. How would I fill each input with one individual item from the array rather than fill each input with the whole array 8 times?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<h3>7. Employer Names</h3>
  <%= simple_form_for @resume do |f| %>
      <% @resume.employerorg.each do |i| %>
        <%= f.input :employerorg,  label: 'First Employer' %> 
        <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

Understanding what's going on here: every time you tell Ruby/Rails to `.each do` an object Collection, you specify a "pointer", if you will, to refer to each object within, in your case, you've specified `i`.

If you're using a simple array as your input, you can just use `i` to output the value.

As Fredrico Mentioned, you should also be utilizing the object's index to generate your ID.

```
<h3>7. Employer Names</h3>
<%= simple_form_for @resume do |f| %>
  <% @resume.employerorg.each do |i, index| %>
    <%= f.input "emp-#{index}".to_sym,  label: "Employer: #{index}", input_html: {value: i} %>
  <% end %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the value of `i` to generate the input. Something like this:

```
<h3>7. Employer Names</h3>
  <%= simple_form_for @resume do |f| %>
      <% @resume.employerorg.each_with_index do |i, index| %>
        <% input_id = "employerorg_#{index}".to_sym %> 
        <%= f.input input_id, label: 'First Employer', input_html: {value: i} %> 
        <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

You need to generate the `input_id` based on the item `index`. Otherwise, all the inputs will have the same name and ID and would be undistinguished.

Comment: thanks Federico, this helped me understand the concepts much better.